# Real Analysis supremum help

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $X = \{y \in \mathbb Q| y^2 <2\}$

Now I am a bit confused by the following:

It is true that $X$ is bounded  by above as numbers such as $1.5$ are upper bounds.
However we say it has no supremum.

Why is that the case? Had the set been defined as $X = \{y \in \mathbb Q| y^2 ≤ 2\}$ would then it have had a supremum?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It has a supremum, but it does not have a maximum (this is true for your both examples because the sets you gave are equal.)

Comment: It does not have a supremum in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Ahhh because root two does not satisfy the condition of being rational....silly me!

Answer (score 2):

The sets $\{y \in \Bbb Q \mid y^2 < 2\}$ and $\{y \in \Bbb Q \mid y^2 \leq 2\}$ are precisely the same set, since there is no $y \in \Bbb Q$ such that $y^2 = 2$.

The set $X$ does not have a rational least upper bound.  Given any rational upper bound (such as 1.5), there exists a *lower* rational upper bound (such as 1.42).

The set $X$ does have a *real* supremum, however.  In particular, $\sqrt{2}$ is a real number and is the least upper bound of $X$.  That is, there is no $y \in \Bbb R$ such that $y < \sqrt{2}$ and $y$ is an upper bound for $X$.